# react apollo Query component vs client.query

Tags: react-apollo

Any idea why this works

```
this.props.client.query({
       query: PRODUCTS_LIST
    })
    .then(response => console.log(response.data))
```

But this doesn't work?

```
<Query query={PRODUCTS_LIST} client={this.props.client}>
          {(loading, error, data) => {
            if (loading) return <div>Fetching</div>
            if (error) return <div>Error</div>

            console.log(data)

            return (
              <div>
              </div>
            )
          }}
        </Query>
```

I'm using `ApolloProvider` and wrapping the component `withApollo(componentName)`.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't need to wrap the component in `withApollo()` provided that the component is a child (doesn't have to be direct) of `ApolloProvider`.

Can we see your code for PRODUCTS_LIST - is it wrapped in gql tag? Does it have the "query" part in it. eg:

```
export const PRODUCTS_LIST = gql`
  query productList {
    productList {
      items {
        id
      }
    }
  }
`
```